# Why do I get a blank page instead of Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am just beginning with Joomla on a linux fedora server (running apache,mysql,php), running in local. I have also installed phpmyadmin.

I have dowloaded/unizip joomla on var/www/html/joomla1 and created a database for joomla1.

Then restarted the server. Selinux is set to permissive.

However when browsing at http://localhost/joomla1/ i simply get a blank page

Any idea what's wrong ? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database permissions (does the user have permissions to access the data), check your error logs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this URL is right?

http://localhost/html/joomla1/

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/httpd/error_log 
Look for anything saying "Fatal:"
This will give you an indication of whats causing the problem